# Dog is rubbing his chin on the carpet and whining

Tags: dogs

My 15.5 y/o male unfixed schnauzer keeps rubbing his chin on the carpet and whines while doing it.

He is taking 1 mg thyroid tabs.

He has also been tilting his head. He's not eating all his food at one sitting, which is unusual for him. I shaved his beard off and I don't see or feel anything unusual.

Comment: is there any reason for you to think this is not a bad tooth causing this,take it to your vet to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like bad teeth. Schnauzers tend to have issues, and honestly, he's a senior citizen, and things like that happen more.

In our case at about 13, our Schnauzer cross had very similar symptoms. Our vet put him under and removed about 7 teeth, and he's been better since. You'll also want to do annual checks and tooth cleaning daily if you haven't already.

You're certainly going to want to get a vet to check it out.